# comparing homotopy colimits of "equivalent" diagrams

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

### Motivation

Let us work in a fixed model category $\mathcal{C}$. I'm interested in homotopy colimits with indexing categories  $\mathcal{I}=\bullet \leftarrow\bullet\to \bullet $ and $\mathcal{I}=\omega$ (the orindal category of finite ordinals). In these cases, by the general theory of Reedy model structure, the category $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{I}}$  admits the projective model structure. So we may speak of the homotopy colimit functor $\operatorname{hocolim}:\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{I})\to \operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$. By functoriality, two diagrams indexed by $\mathcal{I}$ which are isomorphic as objects in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{I})$ necessarily have isomorphic hocolim. Sometimes even more is true: Consider a *not necessarily commutative* diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B @<<< A @>>> C\\
@V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV  @V{\simeq}VV\\
B' @<<< A' @>>> C'
\end{CD}$$

in $\mathcal{C}$, if the vertical arrows are weak equivalences and the diagram *does* commute in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$, then the hocolim of the upper row and the lower row are in fact isomorphic in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$. This is because one can show that the rows are in fact isomorphic as objects of $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C}^{\bullet\leftarrow \bullet \to \bullet})$ by using fibrant/cofibrant replacements and using appropriate homotopies.

### Question

I was wondering whether the same thing can be said in the case $\mathcal{I}=\omega$. That is, consider a *not necessarily commutative* diagram

$$
\require{AMCsd}
\begin{CD}
A_0 @>{f_0}>> A_1 @>{f_1}>> A_2 @>{f_2}>> \cdots\\
@V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV\\
B_0 @>>{g_0}> B_1 @>>{g_1}> B_2 @>>{g_2}> \cdots\\
\end{CD}
$$

in $\mathcal{C}$ which *does* becomes commutative in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$ and whose vertical arrows are all weak equivalences. *Can we say that the homotopy colimits of the upper and the lower rows are isomorphic objects of $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$?*

### Things I tried

I was able to prove the result under an assumptioin which holds for $\mathsf{Top}$ (in both the Quillen and the Hurewicz model structures) and for $\mathsf{sSet}$ (in the Quillen or Joyal model structure). I detail the proof below.

I thought that the same strategy that we deployed for $\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \to \bullet $ would work, and so I followed that line. In other words, I tried to prove that the rows are isomorphic in $\operatorname{Ho}(\mathcal{C}^\omega)$. For this purpose, we may assume that $A_i$'s are cofibrant and $B_i$'s are fibrant, and that the vertical arrows are all (trivial) cofibrations. It is then possible (namely, I used Lemma A.2.3.1 of Lurie's HTT) to find maps $g_i':B_i\to B_{i+1}$ homotopic to $g_i$ making the diagram strictly commutative. This reduces the problem to the case where the vertical arrows are all identities, all the objects are fibrant-cofibrant, and $f_i$ and $g_i$ are homotopic. Assume now that the following additional assumption holds also:

> (*) The terminal object of \mathcal{C} has a cylinder object $I$ such that for any fibrant-cofibrant $A$, the map $A\amalg A\to  I\times A \to A$ is a cylinder object for $A$.

With this assumption, we can conclude the proof by choosing left homotopies $h_i$ from $f_i$ to $g_i$ through the cyclinder object $I\times A_i$, and then considering the commutative diagram

$$
\require{AMCsd}
\begin{CD}
A_0 @>{f_0}>> A_1 @>{f_1}>> A_2 @>{f_2}>> \cdots\\
@V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV\\
I\times A_0 @>>{(1_I,h_0)}> I\times A_1 @>>{(1_I,h_1)}> I\times A_2 @>>{(1_I,h_2)}> \cdots\\
@A{\simeq}AA @A{\simeq}AA @A{\simeq}AA\\
A_0 @>>{g_0}> A_1 @>>{g_1}> A_2 @>>{g_2}> \cdots.\\
\end{CD}
$$

---

For the application I had in mind, the above additional assumption (*) does hold. So I'm rather happy with my situation. But I'm still curious whether it was really necessary. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The argument you used for $\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \rightarrow \bullet$ works for $\bullet \to \bullet \to \bullet \to \cdots$ too. If you have a morphism between chains – that is, a commutative diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ as you have drawn – whose components – the vertical arrows – are weak equivalences, then it is a weak equivalence in the category of chains, and you already believe that hocolim respects weak equivalences.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Oops, that was a typo. I didn't mean to say that the second diagram commutes in $\mathcal{C}$. Thank you for your attention. I fixed the relevant parts of the question.